# Creating "Kind" Cluster fails on wiriting nodes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, load-balancing, kind

I am trying to set up a `kind` cluster for my kubernetes cluster. Unfortunately, it fails after preparing the nodes when it is writing the nodes. I will attach you the output and some information. Thank you in advance for any help!

Cheers

### The Error

```
$ kind create cluster --config kind-config.yaml 

Creating cluster "kind" ...
 ✓ Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.20.2)  
 ✓ Preparing nodes      
 ✗ Writing configuration  
ERROR: failed to create cluster: failed to generate kubeadm config content: failed to get kubernetes version from node: failed to get file: command "docker exec --privileged kind-worker3 cat /kind/version" failed with error: exit status 1
Command Output: Error response from daemon: Container c41566958be2239a9470ef2ea636c4b21958ee7620086f526954a02e4a605106 is not running
```

#### Kind configuration yaml

```
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
kind: Cluster
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
```

#### My nodes

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide

NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE       KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
gemini    Ready    control-plane,master   3d18h   v1.20.2   192.168.2.203   <none>        Ubuntu 20.10   5.8.0-1015-raspi   docker://19.3.13
phoenix   Ready    <none>                 3d17h   v1.20.2   192.168.2.129   <none>        Ubuntu 20.10   5.8.0-1015-raspi   docker://19.3.13
taurus    Ready    <none>                 3d17h   v1.20.2   192.168.2.201   <none>        Ubuntu 20.10   5.8.0-1015-raspi   docker://19.3.13
virgo     Ready    <none>                 3d17h   v1.20.2   192.168.2.202   <none>        Ubuntu 20.10   5.8.0-1015-raspi   docker://19.3.13
```

#### What is running on my cluster

```
$ kubectl get all --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE              NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default                pod/nginx-6799fc88d8-62cjd                       1/1     Running   1          18h
kube-system            pod/calico-kube-controllers-86bddfcff-ccrhg      1/1     Running   7          3d18h
kube-system            pod/calico-node-jddnl                            1/1     Running   4          3d17h
kube-system            pod/calico-node-nxwlw                            0/1     Running   7          3d18h
kube-system            pod/calico-node-stnzs                            0/1     Running   0          52s
kube-system            pod/calico-node-zrxzl                            1/1     Running   4          3d17h
kube-system            pod/coredns-74ff55c5b-kb2nm                      1/1     Running   7          3d18h
kube-system            pod/coredns-74ff55c5b-wsgs5                      1/1     Running   7          3d18h
kube-system            pod/etcd-gemini                                  1/1     Running   8          3d18h
kube-system            pod/kube-apiserver-gemini                        1/1     Running   8          3d18h
kube-system            pod/kube-controller-manager-gemini               1/1     Running   11         3d18h
kube-system            pod/kube-proxy-7fcjz                             1/1     Running   8          3d18h
kube-system            pod/kube-proxy-84rr7                             1/1     Running   4          3d17h
kube-system            pod/kube-proxy-lc88w                             1/1     Running   4          3d17h
kube-system            pod/kube-proxy-v4qd9                             1/1     Running   4          3d17h
kube-system            pod/kube-scheduler-gemini                        1/1     Running   9          3d18h
kubernetes-dashboard   pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-79c5968bdc-mlb4s   1/1     Running   7          3d18h
kubernetes-dashboard   pod/kubernetes-dashboard-7448ffc97b-nq5c9        1/1     Running   7          3d18h

NAMESPACE              NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  41h
kube-system            service/calico-etcd                 ClusterIP   10.96.232.136    <none>        6666/TCP                 3d18h
kube-system            service/calico-typha                ClusterIP   10.109.108.233   <none>        5473/TCP                 3d18h
kube-system            service/kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   3d18h
kubernetes-dashboard   service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.110.70.52     <none>        8000/TCP                 3d18h
kubernetes-dashboard   service/kubernetes-dashboard        NodePort    10.106.194.127   <none>        443:31741/TCP            3d18h

NAMESPACE     NAME                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-node   4         4         2       4            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   3d18h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy    4         4         4       4            4           kubernetes.io/os=linux   3d18h

NAMESPACE              NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default                deployment.apps/nginx                       1/1     1            1           18h
kube-system            deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers     1/1     1            1           3d18h
kube-system            deployment.apps/coredns                     2/2     2            2           3d18h
kubernetes-dashboard   deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           3d18h
kubernetes-dashboard   deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           3d18h

NAMESPACE              NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
default                replicaset.apps/nginx-6799fc88d8                       1         1         1       18h
kube-system            replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-56b44cd6d5     0         0         0       3d18h
kube-system            replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-86bddfcff      1         1         1       3d18h
kube-system            replicaset.apps/coredns-74ff55c5b                      2         2         2       3d18h
kubernetes-dashboard   replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-79c5968bdc   1         1         1       3d18h
kubernetes-dashboard   replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-7448ffc97b        1         1         1       3d18h
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is not concrete, be prepared from the beginning.
There is a huge closed [Cannot create cluster due to docker exec cat /kind/version failing](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1288) github issue without resolution, but..

The issue you encountered is pretty wide and there can be  absolutely different root causes.

[BenTheElder - kind creator/maintainer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1288#issuecomment-631675988):

> This part: Command Output: Error response from daemon: Container
> f2a2d9c8f9c2eca9aeec7f10249eb205b02c8a5f41e5bf1145b5a8e4b63da123 is
> not running
>
> That tells us that the node container is not running. That either
> means the entrypoint failed or your host killed it, both either due to
> some obscure bug we haven't found yet, or more likely an issue with
> your host environment.
>
> Please file your own issue with much more details. This issue is
> non-specific and has discussed many different problems, as outlined
> above.

So please create new issue on Github, most probably that place right now is best for such problem.

I also found you issue could go from [Docker Installed with Snap](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/known-issues/#docker-installed-with-snap). See https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1288#issuecomment-631673479.
Docker from SNAP has knows issues working with Kind  plus its is not actually supperted by KIND team

> snap is in the known-issue document, the snap docker package has a
> number of issues, e.g. no access to temp directories. I don't
> recommend snap for docker and we don't really support this.

---

> A small note: we've worked around most of the snap issues for now if
> you're just managing clusters, but I still don't recommend snap for
> docker.
>
> If you're seeing an issue similar to this, it means the node container
> exited early for some reason. That usually means the host environment
> is broken, but occasionally has meant we need to work-around e.g. less
> common filesystems with device mapper issues.
>
> Please attempt to capture node logs with kind create cluster --retain,
> kind export logs, and file an issue with the logs uploaded. We'll try
> to identify the cause based on these.
>
> EDIT: to be extra clear: "Cannot create cluster due to docker exec cat
> /kind/version failing" is a symptom, please file an issue with the
> details on your specific failure so we can identify the actual root
> cause if you encounter this.
>
> This issue is locked because it got off-topic from the original root
> cause and kept being used for new problems that just happen to have
> the same symptom. This symptom is common for edge cases with the nodes
> suddenly terminating very early on because it's one of the first
> actions we take against the running node.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create the Kind cluster after pruning my Docker containers.  I think it may have been a conflict with a previously installed Kind cluster/container.

`docker container rm <id-of-container>`

After doing this the Kind create cluster command worked for me.

**EDIT**:
Upon further inspection it seems that I had poorly formatted YAML in a config file I was using to create the cluster.  I had mis-spelled a property name.

```
    defaults:
      enfoce: "baseline"
```

should have been

```
    defaults:
      enforce: "baseline"
```

I was following this Kubernetes pod security tutorial when I ran into this issue.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/security/cluster-level-pss/